# How to use keras TimeSeriesGenerator with shuffle=True?

Tags: keras, generator

keras TimeseriesGenerator with shuffle=True provides a random label instead of the one matching the timeseries generated. I'm wondering how to use TimeseriesGenerator so it generates shuffled batches where the labels match the timeseries.

example:

```
# imports
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
import pandas as pd

# prepare data
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1,1],
                   [2,2,2,2,2],
                   [3,3,3,3,3],
                   [4,4,4,4,4],
                   [5,5,5,5,5]])
df2.columns=['f1','f2','f3','l1','l2']
X2 = df2.iloc[:,0:3] # 
y2 = df2.iloc[:,3:]
```

x2:

```
    f1  f2  f3
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
3   4   4   4
4   5   5   5
```

y2:

```
    l1  l2
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   4   4
4   5   5
```

TimeseriesGenerator with shuffle=False:

```
data_gen2 = TimeseriesGenerator(X2.to_numpy(), y2.to_numpy(),
                                     length=2, sampling_rate=1,stride=1,
                                     batch_size=5,shuffle=False)
print('x values: data_gen2[0][0]:',data_gen2[0][0].shape)
print(data_gen2[0][0])
print('y values: data_gen2[0][1]:',data_gen2[0][1].shape)
print(data_gen2[0][1])
```

...produces:

```
x values: data_gen2[0][0]: (3, 2, 3)
[[[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [3 3 3]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]]
y values: data_gen2[0][1]: (3, 2)
[[3 3]
 [4 4]
 [5 5]]
```

which is perfect. However, with shuffle=True, we get:

```
x values: data_gen2[0][0]: (5, 2, 3)
[[[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]]
y values: data_gen2[0][1]: (5, 2)
[[5 5]
 [3 3]
 [5 5]
 [3 3]
 [3 3]]
```

While X2 gets shuffled correctly (i.e. various time series starting at different starting points),
y2 does not match the timeseries from X2.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. It's solved:

The problem with calling:

```
data_gen2[0][0]
data_gen2[0][1]
```

... is that this renews the data provided by the generator twice. So the call to gen2[0][1] actually renews the data in gen2 and returns targets to a completely different batch of samples.

To correct, we need to collect gen2[0] in its entirety and then split the tuple up into x and y:

```
x3,y3 = data_gen2[0]

print(x3)
print(y3)
```

and now, the targets match the samples:

```
[[[2 2 2]
  [3 3 3]]

 [[3 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [3 3 3]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [3 3 3]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]]]
[[4 4]
 [5 5]
 [4 4]
 [4 4]
 [3 3]]
```